# Do I need to use the pseudo column _PARTITIONTIME when querying from a column partitioned table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I created a time-partitioned table on BigQuery by using a date column from the table itself:

```
new_table.time_partitioning = bigquery.TimePartitioning(field='date')
```

I query the data by a simple request as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM t where date="2020-04-08"
```

My question is whether this is sufficient to query the partitioning, and thus reduce costs, or do I need to add also the pseudo columns `_PARTITIONTIME` as outlined in the section on [Querying Partitioned Tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries)?

```
SELECT * FROM t where _PARTITIONTIME = TIMESTAMP("2020-04-08")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer is `SELECT * FROM t where date="2020-04-08"` is good enough for you to engage "partition pruning" and reduce cost.

Longer answer is always consult UI to see if partition filter is properly engaged for certain query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.transactions` 
WHERE block_timestamp_month >= "2020-01-01"
```

This month ->
[image]

Year to date ->
[image]

Comment: When I press on "Details" I see that my table is indeed partitioned by date. However it says Partition Filters not Required. Any idea why that is the case?

Comment: "Require partition filter" is a feature that BigQuery provides for table owner to say "if user wants to query this table, a filter on partition column must be provided". `CREATE/ALTER TABLE with OPTIONS (require_partitition_filter=BOOL) ` can be used to set/unset the flag.